# GET JSON Data from AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a URL with JSON Data. I cannot get this to work because I do not know what to put in the data field. Data is not defined, but it is there as a placeholder for now. What I want to do is save an array of the JSON data I get from the ajax request. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: can you post the declarations of `url` and `data`?

Comment: You can omit `data` if you dont have to pass parameters.

Comment: what does your `url` takes and what does it return , based on that, `data` parameter  can be set. As you are using get method, if no data has to be sent then remove that `data`

Comment: the URL part I have no problem with, its in this format "www.URL.com". I do not know what to do with the data field though

Comment: @khush123456 like Lauromine said if you aren't passing any parameters to your webservice you can leave off the `data:` part...

Comment: when I remove the data field, my ajax functions returns "error" because of the error condition

Comment: is the URL going to a different domain? If so is CORS enabled on the server to allow a request from your domain?

Comment: Have you looked into $.getJson() from jQuery Khush? Very easy to deal with and get the response.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: use this line to see the error in console `error: function(error){console.log(error);}` @khush123456

Comment: Are you completely sure the JSON returned by the server is correct? What if you use `dataType: 'text'` and then parse manually using `JSON.parse()`?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getJSON( url, function( data ) { 
  console.log(data); 
});
```

More examples in [jQuery official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to put anything in the data. The parameter "data" is the response getting from the server.

Use following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'serverurl',  //write your server url here...
        dataType: 'json',  //The data type expected of the server response.
        success: function(data) {
            myServerData = data;  //server response
        }
});
```

Once you get JSON object myServerData, to convert it into JavaScript array use following jQuery:

```
var arr = $.map( myServerData, function(param) { return param; } );
```

Comment: I did what you wrote, but I still cant get the success function to work, it goes to error

$.ajax({
        url: url,  
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function(data) {
            myServerData = data;
            console.log(myServerData);  
        },
        error: function(){
         console.log("error");
        }
});

Comment: May I know which one url you are using?

Answer (score 0):

from [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): data is

> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting.

so data could be a string, eg:

```
data: "firstParam=foo&secondParam=bar"
```

or a data structure, eg:

```
data: {
  firstParam: "foo",
  secondParam=bar
}
```

if you don't need any params, simply omit it in your ajax call.